# How to add jitter to geom_point when already using dodge

Tags: r, ggplot2, jitter

I'm plotting summary stats in front of individual geom_points, but can't figure out how to add jitter to the plots. I think the issue is that I'm already using the position argument to move the High and Low water points away from each other.

```
    waterSymPop_p <- ggplot(aes(x = SymPop, y = Finish, fill = Water, color = Water), data = xanFull) +
  geom_point(position = position_dodge(width = 0.9)) +
  stat_summary(fun.data = "mean_cl_normal", geom = "pointrange", position = position_dodge(width = 0.9)) +
  coord_flip()
```

Here's the plot that produces (obviously not finished with the color scheme, etc)
[image]

I'd like the point to be slightly jittered within each point group (ie, not in a straight line). Thanks for the help!

---

Answer: use `position_jitterdodge`

Amended code and new figure:

```
ggplot(aes(x = SymPop, y = Finish, fill = Water, color = Water), data = xanFull) +
  geom_point(position = position_jitterdodge(dodge.width = 0.9, jitter.width = 0.2)) +
  stat_summary(fun.data = "mean_cl_normal", geom = "pointrange", position = position_dodge(width = 0.9)) +
  coord_flip()
```

[image]

Comment: you mean a jitter dodge http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/position_jitterdodge.html

Comment: Great! I knew it'd be something simple. I'll amend the post to reflect the solution. Thanks!

Comment: @jwb4 You should add your answer as an answer below rather than in the question. Nothing wrong with doing that, and then you can get it upvoted, and the question can be marked as answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drey answered this.

Answer: use `position_jitterdodge`

Amended code and new figure:

```
ggplot(aes(x = SymPop, y = Finish, fill = Water, color = Water), data = xanFull) +
  geom_point(position = position_jitterdodge(dodge.width = 0.9, jitter.width = 0.2)) +
  stat_summary(fun.data = "mean_cl_normal", geom = "pointrange", position = position_dodge(width = 0.9)) +
  coord_flip()
```

[image]